# NodeJS zoho SMTP email service works but not gmail

Tags: node.js, email, smtp, gmail, zoho

My node has settings.js having zoho email works fine and my nodejs application is able to send out emails using zoho as below:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'DEV',
    dbConnectionString:'mongodb://eEvsXieSsW7FXrsw:F45we2opTa45sqD2D@67.217.104.22:60076/?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=goldRestaurant',
    httpPort: 5081,
    httpsPort: 5444,
    httpsEnabled: true,
    emailTransport: {
        host: "smtp.zoho.com",
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            user: "noreply@digiklug.com",
            pass: "Digiklug5672"
        },
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    },
    adminAppHost: "admin.dev.restaurant",
    fromEmail: 'admin@digiklug.com.au',
    ccEmailForDBError: ['info@digiklug.com'],
};
```

However, when I change the setting to gmail it fails with the error as below:

```
/* jshint esversion: 6 */

module.exports = {
    mode: 'QA',
    dbConnectionString: 'mongodb://eEvsXieSsW7FXrsw:F95we2opTa45sqD2D@67.217.104.22:60076/?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=goldRestaurant',
    httpPort: 81,
    httpsPort: 8080,
    httpsEnabled: true,
    emailTransport: {
         host: "smtp.gmail.com"
         port: "465",
         secure: "true",
         auth: {
             user: "contactzaika@gmail.com",
             pass: "BZaika@123"
         }
     },

    adminAppHost: "67.217.117.71:4200",
    fromEmail: 'contactzaika@gmail.com',
    ccEmail: ['azrat@digiklug.com', 'minaza@digiklug.com','admin@digiklug.com.au'],
    ccEmailForDBError: ['admins@digiklug.com.au'],
    toEmailForDBError: ['admins@digiklug.com.au']
    };
```

I start node process as below:

```
sudo nohup node /var/www/Zaika/restaurant_api/api_server/api_server.js --qa&
```

Note: the only thing changed in the settings from zoho to gmail is below:

```
host: "<>",
port: <>,
auth: {
    user: "<>",
    pass: "<>"
```

Rest everything in setting.js remains unchanged.

After changing to gmail the node process wont even start and nohup gets the below error:

```
Calling getOnlineOrderMenu at 23-08-2022 03:50:32

 Calling getPaymentStatus at 23-08-2022 03:50:32 for [object Object]
/var/www/Zaika/restaurant_api/api_server/settings.qa.js:13
         port: 465,
         ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/Zaika/restaurant_api/api_server/settings.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
/var/www/Zaika/restaurant_api/api_server/settings.qa.js:13
         port: "465",
         ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/Zaika/restaurant_api/api_server/settings.js:5:25)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

There are no changes but the email SMTP settings.

Can you please suggest how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: This question did not get the desired attention. Can someone suggest how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the comma is missing at the end of the host line:

##### Original:

```
emailTransport: {
     host: "smtp.gmail.com"
     port: "465",
     secure: "true",
     auth: {
         user: "contactzaika@gmail.com",
         pass: "BZaika@123"
     }
 },
```

##### With the host line comma added:

```
emailTransport: {
     host: "smtp.gmail.com",
     port: "465",
     secure: "true",
     auth: {
         user: "contactzaika@gmail.com",
         pass: "BZaika@123"
     }
 },
```

Give it a retry with the comma added and see if the call will work now.

Comment: The issue was I was suppose to use gmail token instead of plain text password.